# Powershell script date compare not working as expected

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that I run, it was working but I see from time to time it doesnt work as expected. It looks at my Jobs last run time and looks at the current time, and if the current time is greater than 15 minutes of the job last run time it should do something else it will print a fail message. Yesterday when I ran the script the Jobs last run time was the previous day but it still went to the fail message. Here is my code

```
$dte = Get-Date
$jobLastRun = $jobs[1].EndTime.DateTime
$timeDiff = $dte - $jobLastRun

 if($timeDiff.Minutes -ge 15){
    Write-Output "Starting WebApp Swap" 
 }else{
     Write-Output "Current Time: $dte"
     Write-Output "Job Last Run Time: $jobLastRun"
     Write-Output "Time Difference: $timeDiff"
    $ErrorMessage = "AutoSwap Was Run within the Last 15 Minutes"
    throw $ErrorMessage
 }
```

and here is the output of the else statement:

```
Current Time: 03/01/2021 10:22:20



Job Last Run Time: 02/26/2021 17:07:52



Time Difference: 2.17:14:27.8073494
```

Comment: Consider only the minutes and then put a condition on that Minutes variable as a difference. If that Minutes variable is greater or less than 15 minutes, put your conditions accordingly. Problem is you are taking the entire output rather than focussing on what exactly you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `Minutes` only shows the time portion `Minute`.
In your case it's `14`.

> Time Difference: 2.17:`14`:27.8073494

In summary it's `2 days` + `17 hours` + `14 Minutes` + `27 seconds`.

You have to use `TotalMinutes` instead.

```powershell
$datetime1 = [datetime]'2021-03-01 10:22:20'
$datetime2 = [datetime]'2021-02-26 17:07:52'

$datetimeDiff = $datetime1 - $datetime2

Write-host ('{0,-15}: {1}' -f 'Minutes', $datetimeDiff.Minutes)
Write-host ('{0,-15}: {1}' -f 'Total Minutes', $datetimeDiff.TotalMinutes)


# Result:
Minutes        : 14
Total Minutes  : 3914,46666666667
```